# Notify me on comments on a post I already commented on

Tags: feature-request, comments, notifications

Currently the notification system works like this: I get a notification when someone comments on one of my posts, and I also get a notification when someone explicitly mentions my username, i.e. `@username`.

However it happens many times (and it happened to me too a couple of times) for the commenter to forget, or not know he needs to add `@username`, and this likely results in those comments not being read by the intended receiver.

I feel that I should be notified on comments posted on a post I already commented on, even if my username is not mentioned. Something similar to how github pull requests notifications work.

Note that this question refers to posts that are not mine, I always get a notification when someone comments on one of my posts.

Comment: I think this already happens if the comment comes right after one of your comments. If this happened always it'd get overwhelming for some people who have left a comment on a few very active posts. I'd rather it be some kind of opt-in on a per post basis.

Comment: @KevinB I'd personally prefer to be spammed than to lose a question addressed to me :)

Comment: @KevinB At least it does so when your comment was the first, and OP immediately posted after that one. I'm not so sure I really want to get notifications in any other case.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ what if my comment is not the first, or the OP went to sleep before I saw his question and replied 8 hours after?

Comment: then if you're interested in seeing it, you'd have to go back to the post. I usually do this using the "all actions" tab filtered to comments in my activity page. Or if it's a post i know i'll want to come back to later, i'll favorite it.

Comment: @Cristik _"... prefer to be spammed  than to lose a question addressed to me"_ If you are interested to answer a specific question, check back frequently. You can easily find it browsing your [comment actions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1974224/cristik?tab=activity&sort=comments).

Comment: @KevinB I currently do something similar, leave the tab open and periodically refresh it, however this is not 100% reliable

Comment: @Cristik _"however this is not 100% reliable"_ Sure, the question may have been deleted. You don't have the privilege to see deleted questions yet.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm necessarily referring to deleted posts, but having to periodically go through all the post that I think I might have a comment left for me on it's not something reliable

Comment: @Cristik If it's really important for you, then add the question to your favorites (star it).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I already have a large number of questions added to favourites, and I'd also like to keep that section for questions that really deserve to be marked as favourite. And also checking the favourites list is not so easy as checking the notifications counter :)

Comment: Basically, I simply need to be notified when someone comments to a question I've also commented onto. Polling is something I'm currently doing, however we all know as programmers as we are that this is not the optimal solution.

Comment: @Cristik And I don't want to be spammed, that's why I don't think this feature request is a really good idea. Think of a poor person like [_@JonSkeet_](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) here. Their notification inbox would probably get totally useless.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ looks like some other people are on the same side as you, based on the downvotes on this question :) But for me a such feature would be useful. Or at least having a checkmark somewhere to enable/disable it.

Comment: @Cristik I sometimes get annoyed when I can't opt out of comments on a _post_ I made.  Especially meta posts that seem to generate a lot of commentary.  So adding notifications on anything I comment on would flood my inbox so much.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ then it would be useful to be able to watch/unwatch a certain post, regardless you've commented on it or not. You'd then be able to turn off the notifications that bother you, and enable notifications on posts that interest you.

Comment: By default you'd be watching a post you commented on, but later you'd be able to unwatch it

Comment: Use the @-Ping. Honestly, if the other person doesn't know, then (rather bluntly) either sucks to be you, or just tell them.

Comment: If you're looking to get spammed with pings, try the chat feature instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A feature very close to what Jason [proposed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317540/1974224), and that I also [suggested](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317519/notify-me-on-comments-on-a-post-i-already-commented-on#comment312573_317519) in the comments, was added meanwhile.

We can now follow posts we're interested into via the "Follow" link below a question or an answer:
[image]

For followed posts we receive notifications where any action on that post happens: edit, comment, new answer, closed (last two for questions only). Quite a useful feature.

A comprehensive description of the feature can be found in [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network) SE meta post.

Answer (score 10):

This idea has some merit but isn't getting a lot of support. Understandable... it would be overwhelming. It would have to be an option.

What I think might be handy though would be the ability to mark individual posts (questions and answers alike) as ones that you want to receive notifications on.

That said, I wonder if any such system would encourage too much back and forth chat style communication in comments. This would certainly be a downside.

Comment: Subscribing to questions is already possible: you "favorite" the question, getting notifications of any new answer, comment, or edit. This is admittedly galactically poor UX, almost entirely undiscoverable, and completely different to the meaning of "favorite" on most other sites. But that's what "favorite" means on SO. For individual answers, there's no subscribe option, and suggestions to make one seem to get downvoted :(

Comment: Seems your idea was implemented meanwhile, in the form of followed posts.