# Subscribe to or "follow" comments

Tags: feature-request, comments

I would like a way to subscribe to or "follow" the comments/discussions on SO posts.

I know where I can find all of my comment activity, and I know that I get notifications when someone comments on my question/answer or tags me in a comment.

But there are times when I'd like to receive a notification of activity in a comment thread where:

- a new user forgets to tag me, or
- another user contributes to the discussion and doesn't tag me

Like I said above, I know I can manually go back through my comment history to view activity on posts that I've commented on, but I'd sure love a way to "subscribe" to comment threads so notifications would pop up in the notification  bar.

Am I alone in this desire, or is there a backstory that explains why this isn't an option?

Comment: this is a bit similar: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317519/notify-me-on-comments-on-a-post-i-already-commented-on?rq=1 but not a full dupe

Comment: Seeing my question being downvoted like mad, it's at least comforting to see that similar questions get the same reception.  I'm curious though, downvoters, why? What about this question isn't good?

Comment: Downvoting on Meta is different. In general it means that people disagree with the idea.

Comment: It is a feature-request: voting means: *no, we don't want this* see [what is meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: OK then, explain why you don't want this. I'm really curious - why not have the option to subscribe to a discussion? I've read the concerns about being overwhelmed by comment notifications, but that's not a valid objection if you can unsubscribe, right?

Comment: The problem is that it would incitate people to use comments like a chat, which is not their purpose...

Comment: In other words, just favorite the question. This feature already exists.

Comment: @Laurel:  This isn't a dupe.

Comment: @Makoto The answer specifically said that you can receive updates on new comments on the question or its answers, so how isn't it a dupe?

Comment: @Laurel Interesting, I had no idea favorited questions give updates on comments as well.

Answer (score 11):

This isn't a site that's about long-lived conversations in the context of a question.  If you want that, you should go to Chat.

Comments serve their purpose of clarifying and getting more detail out of a question, or to help point out a flaw in an answer.  They're not to be treated as anything other than that; they're temporal and may be deleted at a moment's notice.

Adding the ability to subscribe to comments would elevate them above the station they were meant to be.

Comment: But this is a site where old questions remain useful for a long time, sometimes longer than their author remains active on the site. How to “adopt” such a question to be notified as if you posted it?

Comment: @binki:  That's really not possible; the best you can do is favorite it but no notifications AFAIK go to your global inbox.